# How can I save values in a text file?

Tags: python

How can I save at each step of this loop the values of `out` in the text file `ctr_tr3.npt` in the same column (in `trib[PO4]`)?

```py
N=5
for i in xrange(N):
    os.chdir( 'c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas' )
    os.system( '"C:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\w2.exe"' )
    shutil.move('tsr_1_seg6.opt', 'tsr_1_seg6.txt')

    data = np.genfromtxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\tsr_1_seg6.txt', skip_header=11, names=True)
    input=np.array(data['PO4'])

    trib =np.genfromtxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\ctr_tr3.npt', skip_header=2, names=True)
    out=np.array(trib['PO4'])
    out[i]= input[i]*0.75
```

Comment: It would easier to answer if provide some example input and expected output. Right it is not clear what you mean. And problem is not simple open file and write, am I right?

Comment: at each time step I need to replace the values in the column (PO4) in ctr_tr3.npt, with the values that are in the np.array out, and save ctr_tr3.npt

Comment: Yeah, but from the way you are reading ctr_tr3.npt file one can infer it has some specific structure. You skip some lines, read the header, and then some whitespace separated data. I can give you answer like below but it is just guessing. So what I ask is SSCCE http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: What are there `N` (five) of?  Most of the things you're doing inside that loop look like things that only need to be done once.  Right now, this code is doing the same thing five (`N`) times, except for the very last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but can't you just open the file once, change *all five* values at once, then save the file?

Something like:

```py
os.chdir( 'c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas' )
os.system( '"C:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\w2.exe"' )
shutil.move('tsr_1_seg6.opt', 'tsr_1_seg6.txt')

data = np.genfromtxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\tsr_1_seg6.txt', skip_header=11, names=True)
trib = np.genfromtxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\ctr_tr3.npt', skip_header=2, names=True)

trib['P04'] = data['P04']*0.75

with open('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\ctr_tr3.npt', 'r') as f:
    h = ''.join(f.readline() for i in range(2))

with open('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\ctr_tr3.npt', 'w') as f:
    # first write header from before:
    f.write(h)
    # names from dtype plus newline:
    f.write(' '.join(trib.dtype.names) + '\n')
    # then data, separated with newlines:
    f.write('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str,i)) for i in a]))
```